# HashMap<Long,Long> needs more memory

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory

I wrote this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<Long,Long> mappp = new HashMap<Long, Long>(); Long a = (long)55; Long c = (long)12;
    for(int u = 1;u<=1303564/2 + 1303564/3;u++){

        mappp.put(a, c);
        a = a+1;
        c = c+1;
    }
    System.out.println(" " + mappp.size());
}
```

And it does not finish, beacause the progrm stops with the message in the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I calculated how memory I need to have such HashMAp in memory and in my opinion my computer memory is enough. I have 1024 RAM on my computer.
I use eclipse. Also have set the parameters :
i am starting eclipse from the command line with this:'eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx730m'
And second from Run Configurations  i have set the tab Arguments with this:'-Xmx730m'
And this still gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. 
 What is the reason for this?
ps. Just to add some strange fact - in the bottom right corner of eclipse is shown the heap memory usage, and it is written 130M of 495M. 
Well, when the HashMap mappp increases in size, doesn't this info '130M of 495M' have to change,for example '357M of 495M', 1 second later to be  '412M of 495M' and so on in order to reach this 495M?In my case this 130M stays the same, just a little changes, from 130M to 131M or to 132M.
Strange

Comment: Program arguments, or VM arguments?

Comment: Long does not take 8 bytes

Comment: show what your calculation of how much your program will take memory?

Comment: 1024 RAM only helps if you have at least 30 speed.

Comment: from this site http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/ at the end of the page there is a table and is written that a HashMap takes:  32 * SIZE + 4 * CAPACITY bytes. So, a <Long,Long> entry  is 64bits + 64 bits = 16bytes. These 16bytes i multiply with 1303560 and this gives 1303560*16/(1000*1000) MB = 20MB. And this i sum with the 32*SIZE=32bytes*1303560/(1000*1000)=41MB  ,so up to here 20+41=61MB and finally this thing 4*CAPACITY i ignore and take for example the value 40MB(but probably i have exaggerated it) so all is 61+40=100MB.

Comment: sturcotte06, i know that primitive type 'long' is 64bits=8bytes. You want to say, that 'Long' is larger than 'long'?

Comment: The Eclipse heap memory usage data is the memory used by Eclipse itself, and not your application.

Comment: @citroen Yes, indeed. `long` is primitive so it needs inly 8 bytes, `Long` is object so it needs more memery to keep its state.
Also you forget that `HashMap` needs memory to store elements, key, values, additional memory for resizing during program run.
As for my pc jvisualvm show that your program uses around 734MB max heap.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not allows map of primitive data types. So if you are using Hashmap you will have to pay for boxing/unboxing and overhead of object references.
To avoid the overhead you can write your custom hashmap or use existing implementation from [one of those libs](http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/).

[boxing and unboxing in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should not put millions of items in a map. A `Long` is an object containing an 8 byte `long` field, plus some object overhead. Then you use two instances per map entry.

Since the key is numeric, you could (if the maximum key value is low enough) use an array as the 'map'.

```
long[] mappp = new long[4000000]; // takes 4M * 8 = 32M memory
```

If you need to know whether a value is 'not in the map', use `0` for that value. If 0 needs to be in your map, you can do some tricks like increasing all values by 1 (if the values are always positive).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can not use an array, because my key values are very big,,something like 2^50 but my program doesn't need to put all integers between 1 and 2^50 as a keys in a HashMap, the number of all keys is 2 500 000 all, and the value of every key is between 1 and 2^50. In my post above i am not explaining all this, because i wanted to simplify everything as much as possible.If i know how to solve the above problem with memory, i would know how to solve my real problem. And i still can not understand why a out-of-memory occurs. 300MB or 400MB for such java app should be enough.

Comment: Try to instantiate the `HashMap` with initialization parameters. You see, from time to time the hash table needs to be resized because the load factor is exceeded (75% by default) so temporarily two hash tables exist in memory. Try instantiating with an initial capacity of 2500000/0.75 and a load factor of 1.0: `new HashMap(3333333, 1)`